# Showing entries associated with topic Django

Tags: python, html, django, foreign-keys

I am trying to display the most up to date posts on the homepage. I can query the most recents topics and display them on the homepage however I am having trouble querying the entries associated with that topic. my plan is to display the first 50 or so words of the entries.

**Models.py**

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic that is associated with a certain Category"""
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Topics'

    def __str__(self):
        """Return string represtation of the model."""
        return self.text


class Entry(models.Model):
    """A entry associated with a certain topic"""
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Entries'

    def __str__(self):
        """Return string represtation of the model."""
        return self.text[:50] + "..."
```

**views.py index view:**

```
def index(request):
    """The home page for the blogging website"""
    topics = Topic.objects.order_by('-date_added')[:3]
    entries = Entry.objects.filter(id__in=topics)
    context = {'topics': topics, 'entries': entries}

    return render(request, 'blogging_logs/index.html', context)
```

index.html

```
{% for entry in entries %}
  <li>
    {{ entry }}
  </li>
{% empty %}
  <li>
    empty
  </li>
{% endfor %}

{% for topic in topics %}
  <li>
    {{ topic }}
  </li>
{% empty %}
  <li>
    empty
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You will need to add what field you actually want to display: e.g. {{entry.topic}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When querying the entries you should filter via topic_id field of the Entry not via id field. So you should do `entries = Entry.objects.filter(topic_id__in=topics)` in your index view.

Comment: thank you it worked. For some clarification.. does the variable "topics" from "topics = Topic.objects.order_by('-date_added')[:3]" store the id(s) or does it store the text data(the titles of the topics)?

Comment: @Nick It stores queryset. Use print(topics) just after you make a query and check the console when you visit index page. Using print method this way is very useful debugging tool.